# How to use condtion in xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

```
<courses>
<course number = "1" category = "A">
<title>B</title>
</course>
</courses>
```

I want to pick all @number has category= "A"
I try to use //@number[@category/text()='A'], but it seem no work,
So how can I get it

Answer (score 1):

To get `@number` attribute value of `<course>` node with `category='A'`:

```
//course[@category='A']/@number
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is invalid, you need quotation marks around `1`:

```
<course number="1" category = "A">
```

For attribute values, you never need `text()`. Use

```
//@number[../@category="A"]
```

It means:

- `//@number`: select any number attribute
- `[...]`: which satisfies the condition
- `../`: go up to the parent (element `course` or other)
- `@category`: find a category attribute
- `="A"`: which has the value `A`

Comment: Thx, I will fix that